# Problems with dimensions when fitting image in resnet model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, computer-vision

Maybe there some way to get rid of the avg_pool layer?I cant find solution :(

```
SAMPLE_SHAPE = (32,32,3)
def generate_model(sample_shape):
    inp = Input(shape=sample_shape)
    resnet = resnet50.ResNet50(weights="imagenet",include_top=False)
    x = resnet(inp)
    predictions = Dense(2, activation='softmax')(x)

    m = Model(inputs=inp, outputs=predictions)
    #model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
    # This creates a model
    #predictions = Dense(2, activation='softmax')(x)
    return m
model = generate_model(SAMPLE_SHAPE)
```

> Error: InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most
>   recent call last)
>   ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py in
>   _create_c_op(graph, node_def, inputs, control_inputs)    1566   try:
>   -> 1567     c_op = c_api.TF_FinishOperation(op_desc)    1568   except errors.InvalidArgumentError as e:
>
> InvalidArgumentError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 7
>   from 1 for 'resnet50_14/avg_pool/AvgPool' (op: 'AvgPool') with input
>   shapes: [?,1,1,2048].
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>        15     #predictions = Dense(2, activation='softmax')(x)
>        16     return m
>   ---> 17 model = generate_model(SAMPLE_SHAPE)
>
> in generate_model(sample_shape)
>         7     inp = Input(shape=sample_shape)
>         8     resnet = resnet50.ResNet50(weights="imagenet",include_top=False)
>   ----> 9     x = resnet(inp)
>        10     predictions = Dense(2, activation='softmax')(x)
>        11
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\topology.py in
>   **call**(self, inputs, **kwargs)
>       552 
>       553             # Actually call the layer, collecting output(s), mask(s), and shape(s).
>   --> 554             output = self.call(inputs, **kwargs)
>       555             output_mask = self.compute_mask(inputs, previous_mask)
>       556
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\topology.py in call(self,
>   inputs, mask)    1988             return
>   self._output_tensor_cache[cache_key]    1989         else:
>   -> 1990             output_tensors, _, _ = self.run_internal_graph(inputs, masks)    1991             return
>   output_tensors    1992
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\topology.py in
>   run_internal_graph(self, inputs, masks)    2138
>   if 'mask' not in kwargs:    2139
>   kwargs['mask'] = computed_mask
>   -> 2140                             output_tensors = _to_list(layer.call(computed_tensor, **kwargs))    2141                             output_masks = _to_list(layer.compute_mask(computed_tensor,    2142
>   computed_mask))
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\pooling.py in call(self,
>   inputs)
>       152                                         strides=self.strides,
>       153                                         padding=self.padding,
>   --> 154                                         data_format=self.data_format)
>       155         return output
>       156
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\pooling.py in
>   _pooling_function(self, inputs, pool_size, strides, padding, data_format)
>       269                           padding, data_format):
>       270         output = K.pool2d(inputs, pool_size, strides,
>   --> 271                           padding, data_format, pool_mode='avg')
>       272         return output
>       273
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py in
>   pool2d(x, pool_size, strides, padding, data_format, pool_mode)    3012
>   x = tf.nn.max_pool(x, pool_size, strides, padding=padding)    3013
>   elif pool_mode == 'avg':
>   -> 3014         x = tf.nn.avg_pool(x, pool_size, strides, padding=padding)    3015     else:    3016         raise
>   ValueError('Invalid pooling mode:', pool_mode)
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\nn_ops.py in
>   avg_pool(value, ksize, strides, padding, data_format, name)    2110
>   padding=padding,    2111         data_format=data_format,
>   -> 2112         name=name)    2113     2114
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_nn_ops.py in
>   avg_pool(value, ksize, strides, padding, data_format, name)
>        73     _, _, _op = _op_def_lib._apply_op_helper(
>        74         "AvgPool", value=value, ksize=ksize, strides=strides, padding=padding,
>   ---> 75         data_format=data_format, name=name)
>        76     _result = _op.outputs[:]
>        77     _inputs_flat = _op.inputs
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py
>   in _apply_op_helper(self, op_type_name, name, **keywords)
>       785         op = g.create_op(op_type_name, inputs, output_types, name=scope,
>       786                          input_types=input_types, attrs=attr_protos,
>   --> 787                          op_def=op_def)
>       788       return output_structure, op_def.is_stateful, op
>       789
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py in
>   create_op(self, op_type, inputs, dtypes, input_types, name, attrs,
>   op_def, compute_shapes, compute_device)    3390
>   input_types=input_types,    3391
>   original_op=self._default_original_op,
>   -> 3392           op_def=op_def)    3393     3394       # Note: shapes are lazily computed with the C API enabled.
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py in
>   **init**(self, node_def, g, inputs, output_types, control_inputs, input_types, original_op, op_def)    1732           op_def, inputs,
>   node_def.attr)    1733       self._c_op = _create_c_op(self._graph,
>   node_def, grouped_inputs,
>   -> 1734                                 control_input_ops)    1735     else:    1736       self._c_op = None
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py in
>   _create_c_op(graph, node_def, inputs, control_inputs)    1568   except errors.InvalidArgumentError as e:    1569     # Convert to ValueError
>   for backwards compatibility.
>   -> 1570     raise ValueError(str(e))    1571     1572   return c_op
>
> ValueError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 7 from 1 for
>   'resnet50_14/avg_pool/AvgPool' (op: 'AvgPool') with input shapes:
>   [?,1,1,2048].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You problem/error comes from you input shape. Your input shape is too small.

All pre-trained networks have a minimum of image size. For [ResNet50](https://keras.io/applications/#resnet50) this minimum is 197. Increase you SAMPLE_SHAPE to 197 or to the default size for ResNet50, 224:

```
SAMPLE_SHAPE = (197,197,3)
```

or

```
SAMPLE_SHAPE = (224,224,3)
```

if your images are smaller, resize them to 197 or 224

Comment: I hope to hear other solution)